# How to get alphabatically sorted records on Search View?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-9, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-10

I have created a many2many field containing tags . It shows Search More .. option in the dropdown , when I click Search More button the pop displays records . I want these records alphabetically sorted . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding the following in your py file.

```
    _order= "id asc"
```

Answer (score 0):

In many2many model use `_order = "name asc".

Example:

```
_name='res.partner'
_order='name asc'
```

Hope  it will help you.